# How to serve MP3's using RED5 flash server

Tags: flash, stream, red5, rtmp

I have installed RED5 flash server and 12 hours after installing it, I still cannot serve a simple MP3 file.

So far, If I have understood correctly, you need to create and compile a Java application to simply serve a file!?.... Which seems a little over-complicated to be honest. Never touched Java.

I have used the oflademo however cannot change the directory.

I basically need RED5 to serve MP3 files from a directory (which i will specify), I will be calling the files as normal in a JW player playlist.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Just to add, I want to use red5 specifically. Security purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do this as easy as putting your mp3 files into the oflaDemo/streams directory. If you want to "specify" the directory, this will get a bit more complex since you will need to add a bean to the oflaDemo config file located here: red5/webapps/oflademo/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml. To build your own filename generator you should read this wiki entry: https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/wiki/Customize-Stream-Path